# tkFileDialog and Zipfile error: "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'namelist'"

Tags: python, tkinter, python-zipfile

I'm trying to use tkfiledialog to select a file, and then use Zipfile to extract the contents.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from tkinter import filedialog


ZipFile.extractall(filedialog.askopenfile())
```

Which returns this error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'namelist'
```

Googling it didn't give me a clear answer, but I tried several .zip files and got the message. Any ideas?

Comment: the documentation for `extractall` says the first parameter is a file path. `askopenfile()` doesn't return a file path.

Answer (score 1):

`filedialog.askopenfile()` returns a file object, however, `ZipFile.extractall` takes a string (for the path). What you want is `filedialog.askopenfilename()`, which just returns the absolute filepath of the selected file (which means that ZipFile can use it)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That did it! Thanks for answering what was probably a dumb question. You just put an end to a lot of aggravation.

Comment: @clarktwain If the answer was correct, please mark it as correct so others with the same problem can find an answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the zipfile library incorrectly. Try this:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from tkinter import filedialog


zip_file = ZipFile(filedialog.askopenfilename())
zip_file.extractall()
```